# Problems with update and delete functions

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I have a simple program "phonebook". One function of two these functions is update one record function but when I try to update single record/row it updates all records insted of one. I also have delete function of single selected row and when I press delete button it raises the error below:

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM profile WHERE First=?, Surname=?, phone_number=?") sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error.
```

Here is my code:

```
def create_sql():
conn = sqlite3.connect("phone_book.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile (First TEXT, Surname TEXT, phone_number TEXT)")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
def get_row(event):
    try:
        cursor = tree.focus()
        content = tree.item(cursor)
        row = content["values"]
        one.set(row[0])
        two.set(row[1])
        three.set(row[2])
    except IndexError:
        pass
def update():
data1 = one.get()
data2 = two.get()
data3 = three.get()
cursor = tree.focus()
content = tree.item(cursor)
row = content["values"]
one.set(row[0])
two.set(row[1])
three.set(row[2])
conn = sqlite3.connect("phone_book.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""UPDATE profile SET First=?, Surname=?, phone_number=?""", (data1, data2, data3,tree.set(row)))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
def del_sel():
    try:
        selected_item = tree.selection()[0] ## get selected item
        tree.delete(selected_item)
    except IndexError:
        pass
    conn = sqlite3.connect("phone_book.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM profile WHERE First=? AND Surname=? AND phone_number=?"(data1, data2, data3) )
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
def add_contact():
    if e.get() == "" and e1.get() =="" and e2.get() =="":
        messagebox.showwarning("Input Error","Przyjmniej jedno pole\nmusi być wypełnione")
    else:
        conn = sqlite3.connect("phone_book.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO profile VALUES(:e,:e1,:e2)",
                {
                    'e':e.get(),
                    'e1':e1.get(),
                    'e2':e2.get()
                }
        )
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        tree.insert("",'end',values=(e.get(),e1.get(),e2.get()))
        e.delete(0,END)
        e1.delete(0,END)
        e2.delete(0,END)
    e = Entry(root,bd=2,textvariable=one)
e.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
e1 = Entry(root,bd=2,textvariable=two)
e1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
e2 = Entry(root,bd=2,textvariable=three)
e2.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
e3 = Entry(root,bd=2)
e3.grid(row=5,column=1,pady=5)

tree = ttk.Treeview(root,height=10)
tree["columns"]=("one","two","three")
tree.column("one",width=120)
tree.column("two",width=130)
tree.column("three",width=160)
tree.heading("one", text="Imię")
tree.heading("two", text="Nazwisko")
tree.heading("three", text="Nr Telefonu")
tree["show"]="headings"
tree.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=6,padx=20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update statement should have a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
UPDATE profile SET First=?, Surname=?, phone_number=? WHERE id=?
```

so only the row with the `id` that you must pass as the 4th parameter will be updated.
Change `id` to the name of the column that is the primary key of your table.

Or maybe use the columns `First` and `Surname` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE profile SET First=?, Surname=?, phone_number=? WHERE First=? AND Surname=?
```

This means that you must pass as 4th and 5th parameter the name and surname of the row that you want to update.

For the `DELETE` statement the correct syntax is:

```
DELETE FROM profile WHERE First=? AND Surname=? AND phone_number=?
```

and you should also pass 3 parameters for the `?` placeholders just like you do for the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: (For updating) So I have to add 4th column with Id?

Comment: Don't you have a primary key in the table? A column that is unique?

Comment: I added to this code above function which creates table in sqlite3 should I add sth other?

Comment: You don't have a primary key in the table. So the problem is: when you want to update a row, only 1 row, how will you make sure that only 1 row will be updated? See my edited answer.

Comment: I've got an error cur.execute("""UPDATE profile SET First=?, Surname=?, phone_number=? WHERE First=? AND Surname=?""", (data1, data2, data3))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 3 supplied.

Comment: You must pass 2 more parameters after data1, data2, data3 for the name and surname of the WHERE clause. This is how SQLite will find the row that you want to update.

Comment: But I don't have idea what else I should add. I've got 3 entries firstname, lastname, phone number, nothing else. Could you give me an advise?

Comment: In your question you say: *when I try to update single record/row it updates all records insted of one*. This means that you want to update only 1 row. So which row do you want to update? Say you want tho update the row with First="John" and Surname="Doe" so that the new values are First="Bob", Surname="Smith", phone_number="123456". Then you must pass "Bob", "Smith" and "123456" for data1, data2 and data3 and "Bob" and "Smith" for say data4 and data5.

Comment: Sorry but It still updates all rows. I also corrected delete_sel function now it deletes all records insted of one selected.

Comment: I do not see any changes in the UPDATE statement. The DELETE statement should work if you pass the parameters. How do you call it? What are the values of data1, data2, data3?

Comment: data1 = column "firstname" data2 = column "lastname" data3 = column "phone_number" excactly:data1=( StringVar()) = "one" data2 ( StringVar()) = "two" data3 =( StringVar()) = "three"

Comment: If in the table there is a row with "one", "two", "three" for the 3 columns then only this row will be deleted. If there are more rows with these values then all of them will be deleted. If there is now row with these values then nothing will be deleted. So make sure that the parameters data1, data2, data3 contain the correct values. A DELETE statement with a WHERE clause deletes only the rows that satisfy the condition.

Comment: I added add function and treeview. It looks so